# Is it possible to detect an api update with nuxtjs?

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxtjs

Is it possible to each times my api is update, generate a static site with npm run generate ?

I'll explain my idea.

I have an API linked to Strapi (headless cms) and i get data from this api in my app done with Nuxt. And each times the API is update with new Data or something else, I would like to generate static site whith 'npm run generate'.

Should I do this with a script ? Or is it a function include in NuxtJS ?

Thank's for helping

Comment: Seems a job for `@nuxtjs/pwa` to check update on file version/contents.

Comment: @SCKim's idea is a good one, which I haven't tried.   What we do is trigger the build script through a chron job on the server.